# forest with included TikZ graphs breaks the build (nodewalk stepped to the invalid node)

Tags: tikz-trees, forest, linguistics, covington

With this LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass[czech]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{DejaVu Serif}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{covington}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{subscript}

\makeatletter

% Load forest linguistics library, if available
\@ifpackagelater{forest}{2016/02/20}{%
\useforestlibrary*{linguistics}
}{}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{czech}
\begin{document}
\begin{covexamples}
\item 
\begin{forest}
[C2 [√ [hez]][C2 [C2 ][C1[C1][Q] ] ]{\node [draw,fit=()(!1)(!ll),rounded corners] {};\node at (current bounding box.south) [below=1ex]{\emph{k}};} ]]
\end{forest}
\item
\begin{forest}
[ C2 [C1 [A][C1]]{\node [draw,fit=()(!1)(!ll),rounded corners] {};\node at (current bounding box.south) [below=1ex]{\emph{slab}};} [C2 [\textit{š}]]]
\end{forest}
\end{covexamples}

\end{document}
```

I get this error when building:

```
! Package forest Error: nodewalk stepped to the invalid node
(forest)                nodewalk stack: ",root',for nodewalk,tree,last".
```

Surprisingly the error happens only on the second tree, not the first one, and it happens even when I use exactly the very same TikZ code which works in the first one. Using forest from the TeXLive package (on OpenSUSE) `texlive-forest-2020.176.2.1.5svn44797-42.2.noarch`

What’s wrong with my document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `(!ll)` in the `fit` in the second tree. It is applied at the upper C1, which has only children but no grandchildren, but nodewalk `!ll` says "go to the last child of the last child". Changing this to `(!l)`, the document compiles. (Obviously, `(!ll)` works in the first tree because the intermediate C2 *has* the last child of the last child.)

I could not replicate the funny thing with switching the trees ... if I understood the issue correctly at all.

Incidentally, there is a superfluous right bracket at the very end of the first tree.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Sašo, should the first three anchors in 3.17 work similarly to the ones which follow? That is, should, say, `anchor=parent anchor` work just as `anchor=parent` does? I'm very out of practise, but I can only get the second to work.

Comment: The first three (`parent anchor`, `child anchor`, `anchor`) only work after the node was typeset. The rest (`parent`, `children˙ etc) are just "links" to compass directions which change according to `grow` and `rotate`, so they work anytime. Because a plain `anchor=...` is used when typesetting a node, it makes sense that `anchor=parent anchor` fails while `anchor=parent` works. I should make this clear in  the docs — noted & thanks.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović Ah, makes sense. Thanks. Yes, something in the docs would be appreciated ;).